# How to route to angular page from asp.net mvc view?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-mvc

I want to add some angular pages into an existing mvc project. But routing from mvc to angular doesn't work or I have missed something which I can't understand. It shows error
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'abc/data_activity'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'abc/data_activity'

ApiRouteRegistration.cs (for web api route)

```
 context.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "get_all_data",
            "api/v1/get_all_data",
            new { controller = "DataApi", action = "GetAllData", text = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

AdminRouteRegistration.cs (For route from mvc main layout page)

```
  context.MapRoute(
            "data_activity",
            "data_activity",
            new { controller = "Data", action = "DataActivity", key = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

AdminController.cs

```
public ActionResult DataActivity()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

BundleConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {         
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/angular").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/libs/runtime*",
                    "~/Scripts/libs/polyfills*",
                    "~/Scripts/libs/main*"
            ));
    }
```

DataActivity.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = "~/Admin/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Scripts/libs/styles.css" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
  @section Scripts {
   @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
 }

 <app-root></app-root>
```

app.routing.module.ts

```
 import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
 import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
 import {ResourceTimelineComponent} from "./resource-timeline/resource- 
    timeline.component";

  const routes: Routes = [
   { path: '/abc/data_activity', component: DataActivityComponent }
  ];

   @NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
   exports: [RouterModule]
   })

   export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's even possible to route directly into an Angular app from MVC. What I would do is route to a new, empty MVC page which bootstraps a new Angular app. You'd most likely want a separate `.module.ts` file for this app which only imports what's necessary for this page and whichever Angular routing is required from it.

Comment: I already route a page which is directly route to angular page. But the page I want to show is not main page. it is a child page.

Comment: Weird thing, but in my own `app.routing.module.ts` for a similar use case, I can see I'm using the `forChild(routes)` method and not `forRoot(routes)`. I'm not sure, but it might be what you need.
It only seems to be relevant if this is not your main `app.module` though.